# Group images page specific

Tags: image, vba, ms-word

I would like to group all the images in a certain page or page range by using word macros, the code I have groups all the images in my document, I cannot specify the page number in any of the option,is there a way to do it?if yes, then what is it?

Pasting my code here:

```
     ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
     Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
```

For-each loop might also work but that will not be page specific.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code **(tested)**

```
Sub Gropu_Shapes_By_Page()

    Dim SHP As ShapeRange
    Dim PAG As Page
    Dim REC As Rectangle
    Dim i!

    For Each PAG In ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages
        PAG.Rectangles(1).Range.Select
        For Each REC In PAG.Rectangles
            If REC.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
                REC.Range.ShapeRange.Select False
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next REC
        If i > 1 Then Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
        i = 0
    Next PAG


End Sub
```

As you know it is difficult to assume where each page starts and ends as it depends on paper layout of your final version of document. Therefore, here we assume that `page` refers to one in `printpreview` layout.

**EDIT** Sub version for one page- see comments inside sub.

```
Sub Gropu_Shapes_for_SinglePage()

    Dim SHP As ShapeRange
    Dim PAG As Page
    Dim REC As Rectangle
    Dim i!

        'your number or variable _
        referring to page number _
        instead of 2 below

    With ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(2)
        .Rectangles(1).Range.Select
        For Each REC In .Rectangles
            If REC.RectangleType = wdShapeRectangle Then
                REC.Range.ShapeRange.Select False
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next REC
        If i > 1 Then Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select

    End With

End Sub
```

It could be Subroutine with parameters if someone need it.

Comment: which line in this code refers to printpreview layout? I want to make it generalized because if I give "Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, count:=Spage" it will take me to the desired page

Comment: At the moment it's working for all pages in document. Do you want to run it for single one referred by number??

Comment: yes,or even ,say from, page 10 to page 15, the previous code also works for all the pages

Comment: So, this second solution works for single page which you could run in loop like `for i=10 to 15`, too, where you will change `.Pages(2)` into `.Pages(i)`...

Comment: yes,this may solve my purpose,let me try then i'll let you know

Comment: no both of these are not working, giving a runtime error '5894' --Application defined or object-defined error in For Each PAG In ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages

Comment: proposed code is available only in page print preview. this error number (`5894`) suggesting that you are running that macro in any other, not supported view option.

Comment: no,it is also not working in print preview, rather its getting converted to draft where none of the images are visible